# Resolvent set of second derivative

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Considering the following operator:
$$
A f = f'',\qquad D(A):=\{f\in W^{2,p}(0,1),f'(0)=0\quad and\quad f'(1)=f(1) \}
$$
I want to know how can I find its resolvent set, that is $\rho(A)$. Thank you for help

Comment: Can you show any work?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no work in the present time.